# R Shiny - Dynamically adding dependent inputs using insertUI

Tags: r, shiny

The app below contains an `actionButton`, `Add`, that inserts two inputs when clicked.

The first input is a selectInput with choices `A` and `B`. The second input is a `textInput` if the user selects `A` and a `numericInput` if they select `B`. I'm not sure how to capture this dependency.

I tried attaching an event handler (the second `observeEvent` in the code below) to each `selectInput` that listens to the value of that `selectInput` and renders the second input accordingly using `renderUI`. This doesn't work though. I am also wary about using a render function inside an observeEvent since I have read that using a render inside an observer is not good practice (not exactly sure why). It also looks messy.

The app:

```
library(shiny)

  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton('add', 'Add'),
    div(id = 'placeholder')
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    rv = reactiveValues(ctn = NULL)

    observeEvent(input$add, {

      rv$ctn = rv$ctn + 1

      Id = function(id, ctn = rv$ctn) paste0(id, ctn)

      insertUI(
        selector = '#placeholder',
        ui = div(
          id = Id('div'),
          selectInput(Id('letter'), 'Letter:', LETTERS[1:2]),
          uiOutput(Id('input'))
        )
      )

      observeEvent(Id('letter'), {
        output[[Id('input')]] <- renderUI({

          switch(
            input[[Id('letter')]],
            'A' = textInput(Id('text'), '', ''),
            'B' = numericInput(Id('numeric'), '', '')
          )
        })

      })
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The first UI chunk that is inserted works as expected - both inputs are rendered. However, in subsequent chunks (chunks 2 and 3 in the screenshot below) only the selectInput is rendered.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working code. The main problem was your `ctn` reactive value initialized to `NULL`, because `NULL + 1 = numeric(0)` and `numeric(0) + 1 = numeric(0)`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('add', 'Add'),
  div(id = 'placeholder')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ctn <- reactiveVal(0)
  Id <- reactive({
    function(id){
      paste0(id, ctn())
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$add, {

    ctn(ctn() + 1)

    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholder',
      ui = div(
        id = Id()('div'),
        selectInput(Id()('letter'), 'Letter:', LETTERS[1:2]),
        uiOutput(Id()('input'))
      )
    )

  })

  observeEvent(ctn(), {
    id <- Id()('input')
    selection <- Id()('letter')
    output[[id]] <- renderUI({
      req(input[[Id()('letter')]])
      switch(
        input[[selection]],
        'A' = textInput(Id()('text'), 'ENTER TEXT', ''),
        'B' = numericInput(Id()('numeric'), 'ENTER NUMBER', '')
      )
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that @Stéphane. Your code renders both inputs but when I click `Add` twice and then change the value of the second `selectInput` from `A` to `B`, the dependent inputs in both chunks change to `numericInput` even though I have left the value of the first `selectInput` unchanged at `A`. You can see this more clearly by changing the switch to `switch(input[[Id()('letter')]], 'A' = textInput(Id()('text'), label = 'Text input:', value = 'This is a text input.'), 'B' = numericInput(Id()('numeric'), label = 'Numeric input:', value = 123))`.

Comment: @user51462 Indeed. See my update. I've made some change in the `observeEvent(ctn()`.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again @Stéphane but when I try to use this inside a module, the `renderUI` no longer works. The `uiOutput` shows up in the DOM but it's empty, would you have any clue as to why? I've tried wrapping the `renderUI` in a `delay()` so that it waits until the `selectInput` is rendered before firing but it didn't work. I am using `ns = session$ns` in the module server and modified the `Id()` reactive as `ns(paste0(id, ctn()))`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the etiquette is around this but I could post a new question if you prefer.

Comment: @user51462 Yes, post a new question please. I'm not fluent in Shiny modules, so I can't guarantee I will help.

Comment: No worries, I have posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56407118/r-shiny-inserting-dynamic-ui-inside-a-shiny-module).