# R Shiny - Inserting dynamic UI inside a Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny

The app below contains a module that inserts a UI object each time the `Add` button is clicked. The UI object consists of two inputs:

1. Input 1 is a `selectInput` with choices `A` and `B`.
2. Input 2 is a `textInput` if the user chooses `A` and a
   `numericInput` if they choose `B`.

However, when I click `Add`, the inserted UI only contains Input 1 (the `selectInput`) - Input 2 is not rendered, as shown below:

[image]

Whereas the desired output looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a namespacing issue or if there is a problem in the scoping of the module. Printing the IDs to the console checks out:

[image]

The app is as follows:

```
library(shiny)

# module UI function
modUI <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    actionButton(ns('add'), 'Add'),
    div(id = ns('placeholder'))
  )
}

# module server function
modServer <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns = session$ns

  ctn <- reactiveVal(0)

  Id <- reactive({
    function(id){
      ns(paste0(id, ctn()))
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$add, {

    ctn(ctn() + 1)

    insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = div(
        id = Id()('div'),
        selectInput(Id()('letter'), 'Letter:', LETTERS[1:2]),
        uiOutput(Id()('input'))
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(ctn(), {

    id <- Id()('input')
    selection <- Id()('letter')
    print(list(id = id, selection = selection))

    req(input[[selection]])

    output[[id]] <- renderUI({

      req(input[[selection]])

      switch(
        input[[selection]],
        'A' = textInput(Id()('text'), 'ENTER TEXT', ''),
        'B' = numericInput(Id()('numeric'), 'ENTER NUMBER', '') 
      )
    })

  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

# main ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  modUI('mod1')
)

# main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(modServer, "mod1")
}

# run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried splitting the module up into an inner and outer module. The inner mod creates Input 1 and Input 2 and the outer mod inserts them into the main app using `insertUI`. This gives me the same outcome as before though. The code for this can be viewed below:

```js
library(shiny)


# INNER MOD ---------------------------------------------------------------

innermodUI <- function(id) {
  
  ns = NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns('letter'), 'Letter:', LETTERS[1:2]),
    uiOutput(ns('names'))
  )
}

innermodServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ns = session$ns
  
  output$names <- renderUI({
    
    selection = req(input$letter)
    
    switch(
      selection,
      'A' = textInput(ns('text'), 'ENTER TEXT', ''),
      'B' = numericInput(ns('numeric'), 'ENTER NUMBER', '')
    )
  })
}


# OUTER MOD ---------------------------------------------------------------

modUI <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns('add'), 'Add'),
    div(id = ns('placeholder'))
  )
}

modServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ns = session$ns
  
  ctn <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  Id <- reactive({
    function(id){
      ns(paste0(id, ctn()))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    
    ctn(ctn() + 1)
    
    filterId = Id()('filter')
    
    insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = innermodUI(filterId)
    )
    
    callModule(innermodServer, filterId)
    
  })
}


# MAIN --------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  modUI('mod1')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(modServer, "mod1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also tried wrapping the `renderUI` in a `shinyjs::delay()` to no avail. I would really appreciate any help on this since I'm not well-versed in Shiny modules and don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to make it work by multiple trials-errors. As I understand (I'm still new in Shiny modules), you have to use `session$ns` only for the inputs created in the server.

```
library(shiny)

# module UI function
modUI <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    actionButton(ns('add'), 'Add'),
    div(id = ns('placeholder'))
  )
}

# module server function
modServer <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns = session$ns

  ctn <- reactiveVal(0)

  Id <- reactive({
    function(id){
      paste0(id, ctn())
    }
  })
  IdNS <- reactive({
    function(id){
      ns(paste0(id, ctn()))
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$add, {

    ctn(ctn() + 1)

    insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = div(
        id = Id()('div'),
        selectInput(IdNS()('letter'), 'Letter:', LETTERS[1:2]),
        uiOutput(IdNS()('input'))
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(ctn(), {

    id <- Id()('input')
    selection <- Id()('letter')

    output[[id]] <- renderUI({

      switch(
        input[[selection]],
        'A' = textInput(IdNS()('text'), 'ENTER TEXT', ''),
        'B' = numericInput(IdNS()('numeric'), 'ENTER NUMBER', '') 
      )

    })

  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

# main ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  modUI('mod1')
)

# main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(modServer, "mod1")
}

# run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That's a brilliant observation, thank you! Is this because the input, output and session objects provided in the module server function header are scoped within the specific namespace that matches up with the module's UI function (from the 'Writing server functions' section [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html))? So this allows us to refer to `ns('add')` component of the UI function as `input$add` in the server rather than `input[[ns('add')]]`. As an aside, shouldn't the `id = Id()('div')` in the `insertUI` be `id = IdNS()('div')`?